# Update CVS module from within a Git project

Tags: git, cvs

I use Git to manage my repository, which contains a CVS module from elsewhere. I am not going to make any local changes to the CVS repo, I just want to update it regularly. Currently I make everything in the CVS repo under Git's control, after `cvs update`, I then commit it in Git.

Is there any better (simpler or cleaner) way which allows me to track my Git repo while letting me update the CVS module easily?

Comment: If you aren't going to commit anything to CVS then you could consider adding your update/commit/merge steps into a script so that you can run it all in one go.

Answer (score 0):

What you may want to do is create a submodule in git, export the cvs module to this git submodule using [cvs export](http://ximbiot.com/cvs/manual/cvs-1.11.23/cvs_16.html#SEC142) and commit it to your repo. That keeps the master branch clean of any additional cvs files.

Once you've done that you use a cvs on commit script to keep the submodule up to date when there is a commit - this would be my preferred option. In **pseudocode** it may look like this:

```
#!/bin/sh

mv -R <submodule>/.git /tmp/
rm -rf <submodule>/*
mv -R  /tmp/.git <submodule>/
cd <submodule>

cvs -d<path> export <module>

find . | xargs git add

git commit -a -m "CVS Updates for `date`"
```

### Adding the script to CVS:

- You start with a check out of CVSROOT and copy the script there, not forgetting to make the script executable. `cvs -d<path> co CVSROOT`
- Copy the script into the directory
- Add the script with `cvs add`
- Add the filename of the script to `checkoutlist`
- Add an entry to `loginfo` which will case the script to be run.
- Commit